# I want to understand what some of these Qualys scan means

Tags: jenkins, qualys

There are some flags in this [link](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/qualys-cs/) that I am not able to find any info on.  I tried searching the web and no luck.

I am looking to see if there is more detailed explaination on these flags and flags listed in the website. `getImageVulnsFromQualys imageIds: images, useGlobalConfig: true, isFailOnCVEs: true, isFailOnSevereVulns: true`. Does any one know where I can find more info?